# **at** New Year or **in** New Year

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/new-year) suggests that "**New Year**" is the same as "**new year**". but the following examples suggests that they have different meaning:

> The building work will happen **in the new year**.

But The Guardian usually use **at** instead of **in**

> Sifting through contradictory evidence is common when it comes to choosing the right thing to do to improve our health, not least **at new year** when many of us promise to leave old habits behind and make a fresh start. See the source [here](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2019/jan/04/vaping-by-young-people-remains-burning-issue-health-experts)

**What is the difference in meaning?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"In the new year" (In + definite article "the", always lower case) means "during the forthcoming year starting next January 1st", and is often used to mean the early part of that year. "At new year" (At + no article, "New Year" often capitalised) means "the period, often a holiday, around the transition from one year (the old year) to the next (the new year)". People make "resolutions" at New Year, e.g. to give up smoking.

Comment: Agreed, but I think one of your definitions is a bit loose, and the other a bit tight. To me _in the new year_  does indeed mean "during the forthcoming year", but I think there is an implication that it will start early in the year - in January, or maybe February. _At new year_ means midnight on 31st, but it also means "during the New Year celebrations", which might start on 31st, and go on through 1st and even into the 2nd.